# preg_replace para alterar src de imagem

Tags: php, ssl, https

Eu tenho varias noticias cadastradas em um banco de dados, muitas delas, tem imagens, que apontam direto pro meu site.

Só que elas possuem http e como agora instalei SSL no meu site, preciso que elas fiquem com https.

Eu não quero alterar nada no banco, então preciso de uma preg_replace que altere de http para https, somente tags  no atributo src.

Isso não vale para links, apenas para imagens...

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$re = '/([^<img src=\'"]+):/';

$str = '<img src="http://www.google.com.br"> <img src=\'http://www.google.com.br\'>';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

$str = preg_replace($re, 'https', $str);

print_r($str);
```

Comment: Mas ai ele vai tirar todo o src, quero manter o valor dentro do src e mudar so o http.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um replace simples substituindo o `http://www.domain.com.br` pela sua url.

```
$str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        <img src="http://www.domain.com.br/imagem.jpeg">
        <img src="http://www.domain.com.br/imagem.jpeg">';


echo str_replace( 'http://www.domain.com.br' , 'https://www.domain.com.br' , $str );
```

Comment: Não posso, porque tem links externos dentro deste conteudo, e com isso mudaria o deles tambem.

Comment: Você vai mudar apenas seus links

Answer (score 0):

[exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/XlLTVh)

```
$str = 'Bla bla bla
<img src="http://www.seudominio.com/image1.jpeg">
<img src="http://www.seudominio.com/image2.jpeg">
<a href="http://www.seudominio.com/">http://www.seudominio.com/</a>';

echo str_replace( '<img src="http' , '<img src="https' , $str );
```